# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'tuple' when trying to put input in a web browser

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

In my code, I tried to make the code appear in the URL that has been entered. It just puts bad request. This is also made in python.

## My code is:

```py
import socket

print("Enter a URL Below:")
x = input()


mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('data.pr4e.org', 80))
cmd = 'GET', x, 'HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()
mysock.send(cmd)

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if len(data) < 1:
        break
    print(data.decode(),end='')

mysock.close()
print('If it says "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" at the top, That means the connections are OK. The code is ')
```

## My Output:

```
Enter a URL Below:
https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjU8fr9oJDoAhVB7qwKHX6VB0AQPAgH
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Date: Tue, 10 Mar 2020 15:50:00 GMT

Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)

Content-Length: 308

Connection: close

Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1



<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at do1.dr-chuck.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
If it says "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" at the top, That means the connections are OK. The code is 
>>> 
= RESTART: C:/Users/sharm/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/WebBrowser.py
Enter a URL Below:
https://www.google.com/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sharm/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/WebBrowser.py", line 10, in <module>
    mysock.send(cmd)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'tuple'
```

I just want to make a Web Browser in Python and The browsers on GitHub are a package and I Dislike that.

Give me the Python 3 Code that will fix it.

Comment: Is this homework? Why not use `requests` or at the least `urllib`?

Comment: Did you mean: `mysock.send(' '.join(cmd))`?

Comment: Try downgrading your python version to 3.7. It works fine for me

Comment: Or perhaps: `mysock.send(' '.join(cmd).encode())`?

Comment: Nvm, I fixed it. The code is at https://github.com/Ganesha2282882/Web-Browser and run main.py.